# Remove dups from array column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like so -

```
select 
array_remove(array[n.npi, n1.npi, n2.npi], null)
from lines
```

This query produces an output like this -

```
{"12455640", "12455640"}
{"149269", "3160931"}
{"3160931"}
```

How do I produce this output instead -

```
npi           count
12455640      1
149269        1
3160931       2
```

The count of `12455640` is only 1 instead of 2 because I don't want dups in a single row. For example, `{"12455640", "12455640"}` row in the input.

`3160931` is given a count of 2 because it exists in multiple rows.

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense.  `n` and `n1` and `n2` are not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `count(distinct)` in a subquery.  You don't seem to be starting with an array, so you can use:

```
select (select count(distinct el)
        from (values (n.npi), (n1.npi), (n2.npi)) v(el)
       )
```

EDIT:

You can use the same idea like this:

```
select el, count(*)
from n cross join lateral
     (select distinct v.el
      from (values (n.npi), (n1.npi), (n2.npi)) v(el)
     ) v
group by el
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem because it gives me a result like this - `count column - 1 1 2 1 etc`. It does not tell me which NPI had a count of 1 vs a count of 2 etc.